# Laravel 5.5 Unknown database type enum requested Doctrine\DBAL may not support it

Tags: php, laravel-5, doctrine, dbal

When I run `CMD> php artisan migrate`

I got the below error

> Changing columns for table "gift_cards" requires Doctrine DBAL;
>   install "doctrine/dbal".  Unknown database type enum requested,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it

I downloaded the dependency using composer, it will download version based on my laravel version

```
"composer require doctrine/dbal"
```

the dependency added to my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
}
```

when I run the migrate I am getting the below error.

CMD> php artisan migrate
Migration table created successfully.

> In AbstractPlatform.php line 423:
>       Unknown database type enum requested Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform may not support it.

All my tables has database engine as InnoDB

Comment: What about reading the error messages? They clearly state that Doctrine's enum type is not supported by MySQL. Have a look at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html for alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the dependencies to my composer.json

"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
}

and run the `composer install` command.